# iPhone - kCFStreamNetworkServiceType not recognized?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sockets

I am currently trying to set the kCFStreamNetworkServiceType property of one of the sockets in my iPhone application.

This is the code I have used:

---

```
CFReadStreamRef sipSocketStream;

    CFSocketNativeHandle socket = (CFSocketNativeHandle)aSocket;
    CFStreamCreatePairWithSocket(kCFAllocatorDefault, socket, &sipSocketStream, nil);
    CFReadStreamSetProperty(sipSocketStream, kCFStreamNetworkServiceType, kCFStreamNetworkServiceTypeVoIP);
    MyAppDelegate *appdelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSInputStream *sipStream = (NSInputStream*)sipSocketStream;
    [sipStream setDelegate:appdelegate];
    [sipStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    CFReadStreamOpen(sipSocketStream);
```

---

However this wont compile for me, I get the following errors:

---

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv6:
  "_kCFStreamNetworkServiceType", referenced from:
      VoIPSignallingSocketInit(int)  in SocketTools.o
  "_kCFStreamNetworkServiceTypeVoIP", referenced from:
      VoIPSignallingSocketInit(int)  in SocketTools.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv6
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

---

Is there some important or include I am missing or some framework I have to add to my project? A search on Google has not helped so any thoughts on the issue are most welcome.

Comment: Did you add the CFNetwork framework to your project?

Comment: That was it, cant believe I missed that! If you want to add that as an answer I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: I'm glad it helped you. I've added it as an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must add the CFNetwork framework to your project in order for the symbols defined within, such as `kCFStreamNetworkServiceType`, it to be recognized.

Answer (score 1):

I searched the docs in Xcode. It says those are part of CoreServices, defined in CFSocketStream.h

Answer (score 1):

Add CFNetwork framework in Build phases->Link Binary with libraries

It will work fine.